# changing the multiplier value of a constraint

Tags: swift

I have a menu bar which sits at the top of a CollectionViewController with several different titles about 30 pixels high
. Each title has a small bar underneath, indicating which page/item the user is on, similar to the Youtube app.

```
class MenuBar : UIView {

var menuSectionTitles = ["Title1","Title2", "Title3","Title4"]

var numberOfSectionsInHorizontalBar : CGFloat?

var horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
var horizontalBarWidthAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupHorizontalBar()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupHorizontalBar() {
    let horizontalBarView = UIView()
    horizontalBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(10, green: 150, blue: 255)
    horizontalBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(horizontalBarView)

    horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint = horizontalBarView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor)
    horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint?.isActive = true

    horizontalBarView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    // Set the multiplier/width of the horizontal bar to indicate which page the user is on
    horizontalBarWidthAnchorConstraint = horizontalBarView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 1 / 4)
    horizontalBarWidthAnchorConstraint?.isActive = true

    horizontalBarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 3).isActive = true
    }
}
```

The multiplier value for `horizontalBarWidthAnchorConstraint` is hard coded in at a value of 1/4

I want to reuse the view multiple times across different view controllers, therefore have attempted to change the multiplier of the `horizontalBarWidthAnchorConstraint` like so:

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

lazy var menuBar : MenuBar = {
    let mb = OptionsBar()
    mb.menuOptions = ["Title1", "Title2", "Title3"]
    mb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    mb.horizontalBarWidthAnchorConstraint?.constant = 1/3
    return mb
}()
}
```

But this method does not work.  I can not find a way to change the multiplier value from inside the ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

In the code here you are changing the `constant` of the constraint, not the `multiplier`. Is that correct?

Also note, the `multiplier` of a constraint is read only. You cannot change it. If you want to change the `multiplier` of a constraint applying to a view then the only to do it is to add a new constraint with the new multiplier and remove the old constraint.

The **only** part of a constraint that is read/write is the `constant` property.

Comment: Makes sense, managed to come up with the complete answer from this :) Make sure my edit to your answer is correct if you could and I'll mark answer correct